# Auto Highlight the https:// part of the link in the new insert link wizard

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor, external-links

Stack Overflow has updated the insert link wizard

[image: image of the link wizzard]

Unfortunately the `https://` that is automatically in the box is not highlighted.  This means you can't just paste the link into the box anymore as you would get a link like

```
https://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...
```

in the text box.  Could we have the `https://` part automatically highlighted like it used to be so we can just paste the link without having to highlight/remove the default content?

Comment: This **is causing errors**. People *are* entering `https://https://`. So far, that error has slipped through for 15 posts ([14](//stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2F&pagesize=50) + [1](//stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fhttp%3a%2f%2f&pagesize=50)). That's 15/(54 + 14) = 22% of all such errors on the Stack Exchange Network in the very brief time the dialog has been working this way. [Note: I have not double checked each occurrence, it's possible that *a few* are intentional.] At this rate, the problem is going to be quite significant.

Comment: Looks like someone is going through and correcting these errors, so the links above will no longer show the numbers I've indicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Our intrepid balpha jumped on this, fixing both the bug and the broken links that resulted from it. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Give balpha my thanks for doing this so quickly.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank *you* for pointing it out so quickly!

Comment: Thanks (both balpha and Shog9) for quickly fixing and responding to this. It's *really* nice to see the times when Stack Exchange reacts rapidly to reported problems.